# sending big attachments using C# ASP.NET 3.5 System.Net.Mail

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, email-attachments, system.net.mail

I have been trying to send a big attachment (9 MB) using C# ASP.NET 3.5 System.Net.Mail. I read that .NET 4.0 had a bug which doesn't allow this, but .NET 3.5 is fine. 
[.NET 4.0 Fails When sending emails with attachments larger than 3MB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803132/net-4-0-fails-when-sending-emails-with-attachments-larger-than-3mb)

Since .NET 3.5 doesn't close the session properly after an email is sent, I added this line before it's sent:

```
    smtpClient.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 2;
```

The line

```
    smtpClient.Send(email);
```

is still throwing this error:

```
    Exceeded storage allocation. The server response was: 5.3.4 Error: message file   too big:   
    at System.Net.Mail.DataStopCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode, String serverResponse)
    at System.Net.Mail.DataStopCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn)
    at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.OnClose(Object sender, EventArgs args)
    at System.Net.ClosableStream.Close()
    at System.Net.Mail.MailWriter.Close()
    at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
```

Changing the encoding doesn't help. This corrupts the attachment:

```
    email.Attachments[0].TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.SevenBit;
```

Could someone please help? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The server response was: 5.3.4 Error: message file   too big:

That tells you everything you need to know: **The Server** dissallows sending attachments of that size. There's nothing wrong with your code, at least not because of a bug in .NET or something like that. The error message you link related to a bug in .NET is very different from what you are getting. It's unrelated.