# Random "Index was outside the bounds of the array" as an SmtpException

Tags: c#, email, smtpclient, system.net.mail

I'm getting an exception randomly with the Send method shown below. The exception I'm getting is:

```
Exception information:
    Exception type: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException
    Exception message: Failure sending mail.

Inner exception information (level 1):
    Exception type: System.IndexOutOfRangeException
    Exception message: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
```

My method looks like the following:

```
public void Send(string from, List<string> to, string subject, string body, List<string> attachments)
{
    var email = new MailMessage();
    var server = new SmtpClient();

    // Add each mail property
    email.From = new MailAddress(from);
    foreach (var t in to)
        email.To.Add(t);
    email.Subject = subject;
    email.IsBodyHtml = true;
    email.Body = body;
    foreach (var a in attachments)
        email.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(a));
    server.Send(email);
}
```

Before calling this override, I'm verifying that the to List and the attachment list both have at least a single value and that the value is valid.

The exception occurs on sever.Send.

Comment: this bug?http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/544562/cannot-send-e-mails-with-large-attachments-system-net-mail-smtpclient-system-net-mail-mailmessage#details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like the same issue as [this question about .NET 4.0 failing when sending emails with large attachments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803132/net-4-0-fails-when-sending-emails-with-attachments-larger-than-3mb).  Microsoft has posted a [bug fix here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=30226).